# Automating an Application using COM

Tags: com, vbscript, automation, dispatch

I am building an automation interface for an existing application. After implementing a DLL server and an EXE server (mainly for getting familiar with the basics of COM) I am now at the point where I generate a type library from an IDL file and can, for example, basically automate my application from VBScript:

```
Set oApp = CreateObject("MyApp.1") 
oApp.ShowAboutBox()
```

This simple call to a function that takes no parameters works. The next step I want to take is call a function that takes a parameter.

The signature of the function in the IDL file is

```
HRESULT CreateSomeChildWindow([out, retval] MyChildWindow** ppChildWindow);
```

and in VBScript I assume it would be

```
Dim oWnd As MyChildWindow
oWnd = oApp.CreateSomeChildWindow()
```

This call already works **in C++** although `MyChildWindow` is not currently registered as a COM object in the registry. The reason `MyChildWindow` *doesn't need* to be registered is that `CreateSomeChildWindow` simply returns the interface pointer to the created `MyChildWindow` object in a parameter. And the reason it *isn't* registered is that I want to avoid redundancy, and also I don't want `MyChildWindow` to be instantiated directly (e.g. by calling `CreateObject` in VBScript).

**Question:**

Now I'm trying to find out whether it will be necessary to register `MyChildWindow` after all. Is my assumption correct that in order to call `CreateSomeChildWindow` in VBScript

- I need to write `Dim oWnd As MyChildWindow`
- For this to work, `MyChildWindow` must be registered

And if the answer to that is *yes*, hopefully clients still can't `MyChildWindow` directly, since I don't implement a class object for it? Or will I have to implement a class object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your out/retval is not an object (on the scripting side), it is an interface pointer. And since the method `CreateSomeChildWindow` is on IDL, in type library, in registered type library - scripting/automation is aware of interface definition, such as methods etc, because the whole type library is already registered. You are already well set, no additional registration required.

When caller receives an interface pointer, it does not care what object the pointer belongs to. Interface pointer alone is good enough, and scripting/automation environment known how to deal with it.

On the callee side however, you need to return an interface pointer, and you are dealing with objects. So you need some class which implements this interface and you return this object's interface.

Comment: Sounds good, but calling `oApp.CreateSomeChildWindow()` gives me an error, saying the number of parameters is incorrect. What syntax do I need? As mentioned, it works calling from C++ - all the required code is there as far as the server is concerned.

Comment: Syntax looks good (at least looking at quoted in the question). A reason I would check first is that you re-registered type library after you updated it and added a new method there. It might so happen that scripting still somehow uses older syntax.

Comment: Hmm, no, the IDL file hasn't changed for a while and the type library has just been registered.

Comment: One thing I don't understand though is how you define `MyChildWindow` on IDL.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer since it addresses the question as originally asked - thanks! There are still some problems related to the VBScript binding, but I'll enter a separate question for those if necessary.

Comment: You might also want to check out `ATL`+`VBS` automation sample I wrote a few weeks ago, which also shows all the same concepts (IDL, automation, methods etc.): http://alax.info/blog/1381